# I constantly die

Tags: borderlands-2

It's probably me that's doing something wrong since most players say this game is too easy, but I just can't seem to handle it. I'm playing as Zero at level 5, and I have died like ten times to packs of Bullymongs. Even if get a headshot, it maybe chips away 30% of health, and then I get swamped by 4 or 5 others. Trying to shoot them with my pistol hardly does any damage and one hit pretty much removes my shield, even the monsters that are below me in health. Using the decoy skill doesn't help much either.

I've done all the side missions I can find and none of the shops have any better weapons to buy.

Either I'm doing something seriously wrong or the game balance is absolutely bonkers. How can I beat a group of monsters that completely swarms me?

Comment: B2 is all about kitinig IMHO find long distance weapon maybe

Comment: I HAVE a long range weapon. As I wrote, I have a sniper rifle. And kiting doesn't do much since even if I sprint, they are able to hit me multiple times.

Comment: get exp off rakks and maurauders by sniping them ontop of the cliff at southern shelf

Comment: I don't understand how this game can be considered easy. While playing Axton I died a LOT, not only during the early levels. Borderlands 2 is one of the hardest games I've ever played.

Comment: The very beginning of a bordelrands character is the same for almsot everyone. I advise you avoid sniper and use a SMG or Assault Rifle in the early stages. You should not have trouble at level 5 killing enemies so you might be doing smethng wrong.

Comment: Be a Hunter. They never die, you know.

Comment: @BenBrocka They infrequently perish, I've heard also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sniper Rifles are really tricky to use against enemies that can close with you, especially when you're playing solo.  In a larger group, it's easier to hang back and have others tank for you.

Automatic weapons, like the SMG and Assault Rifle classes, tend to be good "all around" damage dealers and are better for encounters with multiple enemies and where you might get swarmed.

At the outset, it can be hard to defeat the chicken and egg problem of "I could find/buy better weapons if I could just get a kill, but I can't get a kill because I don't have good weapons."  Every kill you manage to get does boost your experience, and on the first couple of playthroughs enemies don't scale to your level, so eventually things will get easier.

There are several Marauder Camps in Southern Shelf that you can tackle at range.  A few of the enemies will charge you, but once dealt with you can pick at the ranged foes from a distance.  Their accuracy at range stinks, so your shields ought to hold out better.

Alternatively, you can go back and fight Knuckle Dragger (the Bullymong who stole Claptrap's eye) again, as he often drops good loot.  Unfortunately, it's all underleveled for you, but it still might give you a bit of an advantage.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use your best weapons regardless of type.  Until you have perks, all the weapons work the same for all the characters.
2. When you're downed, get a kill to pop back up.  This is hard to do with a sniper rifle, but easier with other weapons.
3. If you're truly outgunned, go back to a lower level area to get more levels/gear.

Check out this guy's video.  Although he is clearly skilled enough at the game, he is downed several times in the area you mention.  Getting downed is just part of the game.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to use the sniper rifle, i would advise using a pistol for a back up and leveling up on you sniper and knife tree (they help each other). Also you can come back to other quests then you can get the quests done.

Answer (score 0):

For bullymongs, use a fire weapon. Even a relatively poor fire pistol will serve you better than most of the low-level sniper rifles.

Save the sniper rifle for distant targets that can't close fast with you. They're excellent for use against bandits trying to hide behind cover, for example.